# PDO statement fetchall not returning required result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have read all other PDO topic in stackoverflow and tried all the stuff, but still its not working, i don't know whats wrong

on the Edit/Change Password page

I am using this code

```
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once './../account/config.php';
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$opwd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['oldpwd']);
$npass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newpwd']);
$anpass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['renewpwd']);

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count from users where id = :id";
try {
$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(":id", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

here, $result[0]["password"] is not fetching the result from table **users** and column **password**

I even tried $result["password"] but not working,
in other pages same method is working very perfect but here its not fetching result

So, even user puts correct old password, its returning **Current Password is Incorrect**

```
if($result[0]["password"] !== $opwd) {
$msg = "Current Password is Incorrect";
} 
elseif($npwd !== $rnpwd) {
$msg = "New Passwords did not match.";
}
elseif (($result[0]["password"] === $opwd) &&  $npwd === $rnpwd) {
$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET  (`password`, `retype`) = (:npswd , :anpwd) WHERE `id` = :id";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":npswd", $npass);
    $stmt->bindValue(":anpwd", $anpass);
    $stmt->bindValue(":id", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $msg = "Your Password is changed successfully";
    $msgType = "success";
    }
   else {
   $msg = "Error Occured. Please Contact us if you have some issue.";
   }
   }
  catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
 }
 }
```

Please guide me what am i missing here

Comment: If you had read about PDO you wouldn't be using `mysql_real_escape_string`!

Comment: Your sql query returns one column, called `count` (if the id exists). if you want it to return a password, you would have to have that in the sql!

Comment: eg `"SELECT password from users where id = :id"`. You have other issue though, for a start it looks like you are storing plain text passwords, which is a massive no

Comment: i tried to save passwords using md5 earlier, but later i read an article that it is not worthy to use md5 as if someone accessed your database, he surely can use reverse md5

Comment: You should be using `password_hash()`.

Comment: Why do you need to store the retyped password in the database? You should just check that `$npass` and `$anpass` are equal. If they're not the same, you don't update the password. And if they are the same, you only need to store one of them.

Comment: That would be really great, i did not think about it. Thanks Barmar